# How to get a highest value from Nth colum withouth knowing column name

Tags: mysql, pdo

How to get a highest value from the second column in a table, without knowing column name? In a single SQL query?

I got a set of tables where the value I'd like to get is always in a second column (that's part of the way tables are always made), but the name of this column is different in each table. So I could use some simple SQL query that can obtain this value. Any ideas? I know it's doable with PHP and additional query to extract the names of columns, but I'm looking for elegant, purely SQL solution :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: @JohnConde - nothing really, I have no clue how to solve it :) And yes - I looked for solution, couldn't find it. Also: It's not a homework. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's gonna be a tedious process. But, if it's necessary, you may use `ORDINAL_POSITION` column in the `information_schema.columns` table to get the Nth column name.

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = "your table name" 
AND ordinal_position = 1 --replace 1 with your N
```

[Check this.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/informationschemacolumns/)

Answer (score -1):

The obvious solution is to change the data structure. making it *[relational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model)* and *[normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)*.
In a properly designed database such a question like your just simple can't be.
There is always one field which you can query for the highest value. And position in the field list absolutely doesn't matter.

As a side effect of refactoring your database structure, you will have a solution for the hundreds other problems you will have in the future.

Comment: Relations and normalization don't have anything to deal with it. I think you misunderstood the question and the issue.